# Android list Fragments overlap

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to replace one list fragment with another one (also list). But they overlaps.

Fragments were added dynamically:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    CatalogFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

and I'm trying to replace this `CatalogFragment` with `LessonFragment` in `OnFragmentInteractionListener` when the item of `CatalogFragment`'s list item clicked like this:

```
//        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
//        fragmentManager.popBackStack();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_catalog, LessonsFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I've been trying to pop previous item in backStack. Also tried to give the name of backStack of `CatalogFragment` and then remove it manually. Doesn't work. 
Both of fragments are getting displayed at the same time.

I have tried first 10 solutions of google and tried to use standard *developer.android*'s solution of replacement. Fail.

Please help if you know how. Thanks in advance.

P.S. Tell if some more code needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you added `CatalogFragment` in a layout: `R.id.container`, but you replace your `LessonsFragment` in another layout: `R.id.fragment_catalog`. I think that it's the reason why 2 fragments display at the same time. You should only use 1 `Layout` view to display fragments with you want only 1 visible.

Comment: Nah, that didn't help. You see, `container` is empty `FrameLayout` with only `NavigationDrawer Fragment`. And at first I'm not adding `CatalogFragment`, I'm replacing it with `container`. Thats why (I belive) it lies at top. So I have to replace again this `CatalogFragment` with `LessonFragment`, not `container`. Well, thats my opinion.